# Dynamic change set of active pirobox links

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I am trying to deactivate links of not current pirobox gallery on change category in menu.
That`s my HTML:

```
<ul class="thumbs">
    <li><a class="wedding" href="..." rel="iframe-201-113""><img src="..."></a></li>
    <li><a class="funeral" href="..." rel="iframe-201-113""><img src="..."></a></li>
    <li><a class="ceremony" href="..." rel="iframe-201-113""><img src="..."></a></li>
    <li><a class="wedding" href="..." rel="iframe-201-113""><img src="..."></a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I am trying to fully remove pirobox, set 'pirobox_' prefixes for other links and run pirobox again, but i can`t kill pirobox. Links, that was initialized earlier still works.

It`s my JS code:

```
//On choise category
$('.nav li a').click(function(){
    //kill pirobox
    $($.piroBox_ext).remove();
    $(".piro_overlay").remove();
    $(".pirobox_content").remove();
    $("#imgCache").remove();

//replace prefixes
    $('ul.thumbs a').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('class',$(this).attr('class').replace(/pirobox_/,''))
    });
    $('ul.thumbs a.'+current).each(function(){
        $(this).attr('class','pirobox_'+$(this).attr('class'));
    });
    //init pirobox again
    $().piroBox_ext({
        piro_speed : 700,
        bg_alpha : 0.5,
        piro_scroll : true
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Method from pirobox library. http://www.pirolab.it/pirobox/

Answer (score 1):

That solution only works for vanilla pirobox. For Extended you need instead:

```
$(".piro_overlay").remove()
$(".piro_html").remove();
```